# Single Row Locking in MySQL with Python Flask

Tags: python, mysql, flask, locking

I have coded a Python Flask application, and I run two instances of it on two different web servers. Every time a HTTP request is made to the application, a new connection to my MySQL database is created. In my application, there is a table of accounts, and each account has an integer balance. The problem is, I discovered that if a user makes multiple requests to a URL route that subtracts from an accounts balance quickly, they can end up with a negative balance because the two requests are executed at the same time.

Basically my question is, how can I make it so that when I am running a query on a row's balance column, that row will be untouchable by any other connections, of which there may be many? I would like to leave all other rows in the table editable, I would just like to kind of "lock" a single row so that users can't "double spend" their balance, etc., without locking the entire table for performance's sake.

Or perhaps I am approaching this completely wrong -- sorry if I am, I'm quite new to this.

I did ask a question on a different account when I first started coding this application regarding the proper way to do this, but it got downvoted to hell, and now I'm in this mess.

I have looked into MySQL transactions, but I don't understand them very well, and I don't think that I should be using them here, or am I wrong?

Thank you!